# The relationship between MULTIPLICITY and PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT

Tags: perl, xs, perlapi

What is the relationship between the Perl API macros `MULTIPLICITY` and `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`?

According to [`perlguts`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#How-multiple-interpreters-and-concurrency-are-supported):

> One macro controls the major Perl build flavor: `MULTIPLICITY`. The
>   `MULTIPLICITY` build has a C structure that packages all the interpreter
>   state. With multiplicity-enabled perls, `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` is also
>   normally defined, and enables the support for passing in a "hidden"
>   first argument that represents all three data structures.

(by the way, which *"three data structures"* are referred to here?)

I have noticed that when I build perl with [`usethreads`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.30.0/INSTALL#Threads):

```
./Configure -des -Dusethreads
```

the macros `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` and `MULTIPLICITY` will both be set (defined). 
Also, in [`embedvar.h`](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/perl-5.30.0/embedvar.h) there is a comment that may be relevant:

> The following combinations of `MULTIPLICITY` and
>   `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`    are supported:
>        1) none
>        2) MULTIPLICITY  # supported for compatibility
>        3) MULTIPLICITY && PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
>
> All other combinations of these flags are errors.
>
> only #3 is supported directly, while #2 is a special
>     case of #3 (supported by redefining vTHX appropriately).

- So, when writing XS code is there any difference in writing
  `#ifdef MULTIPLICITY` versus writing `#ifdef PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`?
- What is the history behind the two variables? It seems like they today could be reduced to a single. For example, what would happen if all occurences of `MULTIPLICITY` was replaced with `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` in the perl source? What would it break?

Comment: The `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` macro will pull `MULTIPLICITY` in, go look at the [`perl.h`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/45f8e7b102987a417bf55438e858cedced8aedbe:/perl.h#l169) header. All that nastiness control what the `pTHX_`, `dTHX_`, etc macros will expand to.

Comment: Re "*So, when writing XS code is there any difference in writing `#ifdef MULTIPLICITY` versus writing `#ifdef PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`?*", Why would use either? (What are you trying to check for?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have found so far. Running [`sh Configure -des`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.30.0/INSTALL#Run-Configure) creates the header `config.h`. This header file will:

- define `USE_ITHREADS` if and only if `Configure` was given the flag `-Dusethreads`, e.g.:

  ```
  sh Configure -des -Dusethreads
  ```
- define `MULTIPLICITY` if and only if `Configure` was given the flag `-Dusemultiplicity`:

  ```
  sh Configure -des -Dusemultiplicity
  ```
- Setting `MULTIPLICITY` through `ccflags` will **not** set `MULTIPLICITY` in `config.h`, e.g.:

  ```
  sh Configure -des -Accflags="-DMULTIPLICITY"
  ```
- `Configure` has no `-D` flag for `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`, and defining it through `ccflags` will **not** define it in `config.h`.

The generated `config.h` header is `#include`d by [`perl.h`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/perl.h). Note, that the latter header is also usually included by Perl XS extension files (`.xs`-files).
At line 59 in [`perl.h`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/perl.h#l59) we have:

```
#ifdef USE_ITHREADS  
#  if !defined(MULTIPLICITY)
#    define MULTIPLICITY
#  endif
#endif

#ifdef PERL_GLOBAL_STRUCT_PRIVATE
#  ifndef PERL_GLOBAL_STRUCT
#    define PERL_GLOBAL_STRUCT
#  endif
#endif

#ifdef PERL_GLOBAL_STRUCT
#  ifndef MULTIPLICITY
#    define MULTIPLICITY
#  endif
#endif

#ifdef MULTIPLICITY
#  ifndef PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
#    define PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
#  endif
#endif
```

This means that:

- if `-Dusethreads` is given, `USE_ITHREADS`, `MULTIPLICITY`, and `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` will all be defined.
- if `-Dusemultiplicity` is given, `MULTIPLICITY` and `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` will be defined, whereas `USE_ITHREADS` will be undefined.
- if none of `-Dusethreads` or `-Dusemultiplicity` is given `USE_ITHREADS`, `MULTIPLICITY`, and `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` will all be undefined.
- it is not possible to have `MULTIPLICITY` defined and `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` undefined (unless one uses `ccflags`, but then this will only be during the perl build. XS extension modules that include `perl.h` will not see this)

So extension modules can usually assume that either:

- `MULTIPLICITY` and `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` are both defined, or
- `MULTIPLICITY` and `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` are both undefined.