# threaded Perl crosscompiling issue

Tags: perl, cross-compiling

I try to crosscopling (arm-linux-gnueabihf) the latest Perl 5.38.0 from cpan.org with this [https://arsv.github.io/perl-cross/download.html](https://stackoverflow.com). Compiling without -Dusethreads makes just fine, but with -Dusethreads errors occured:

```
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `S_MgBYTEPOS':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x2ac8): undefined reference to `PL_curcop'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_TOPMARK':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x2b00): undefined reference to `PL_markstack_ptr'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_POPMARK':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x2b48): undefined reference to `PL_markstack_ptr'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_gimme_V':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x49e8): undefined reference to `PL_op'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x49ec): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushblock':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4ba8): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bac): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bb0): undefined reference to `PL_curcop'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bb4): undefined reference to `PL_markstack_ptr'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bb8): undefined reference to `PL_markstack'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bbc): undefined reference to `PL_scopestack_ix'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bc0): undefined reference to `PL_curpm'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bc4): undefined reference to `PL_tmps_floor'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4bc8): undefined reference to `PL_tmps_ix'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_popblock':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4c6c): undefined reference to `PL_markstack'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4c70): undefined reference to `PL_markstack_ptr'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4c74): undefined reference to `PL_scopestack_ix'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4c78): undefined reference to `PL_curpm'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4c7c): undefined reference to `PL_curcop'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4c80): undefined reference to `PL_tmps_floor'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_topblock':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4d24): undefined reference to `PL_markstack'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4d28): undefined reference to `PL_markstack_ptr'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4d2c): undefined reference to `PL_scopestack_ix'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4d30): undefined reference to `PL_curpm'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4d34): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4d38): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushsub':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4eec): undefined reference to `PL_op'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4ef0): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4ef4): undefined reference to `PL_comppad'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_popsub_common':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4fd4): undefined reference to `PL_comppad'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4fd8): undefined reference to `PL_curpad'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x4fdc): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_popsub_args':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5108): undefined reference to `PL_defgv'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x510c): undefined reference to `PL_curpad'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushformat':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5280): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5284): undefined reference to `PL_defoutgv'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5288): undefined reference to `PL_comppad'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_popformat':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x539c): undefined reference to `PL_comppad'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x53a0): undefined reference to `PL_curpad'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x53a4): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_push_evalortry_common':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x54a8): undefined reference to `PL_eval_root'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x54ac): undefined reference to `PL_parser'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x54b0): undefined reference to `PL_top_env'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x54b4): undefined reference to `PL_in_eval'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x54b8): undefined reference to `PL_op'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pusheval':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x555c): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushtry':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x55b0): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_popeval':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x56a8): undefined reference to `PL_in_eval'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x56ac): undefined reference to `PL_eval_root'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x56b0): undefined reference to `PL_curstackinfo'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushloop_plain':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x56f0): undefined reference to `PL_op'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushloop_for':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5750): undefined reference to `PL_op'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushwhen':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x58e8): undefined reference to `PL_op'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_pushgiven':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5958): undefined reference to `PL_op'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_cx_popgiven':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x59d4): undefined reference to `PL_defgv'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_foldEQ_locale':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5c64): undefined reference to `PL_fold_locale'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_mortal_getenv':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x5d08): undefined reference to `PL_scopestack_ix'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `S_new_body':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x62a8): undefined reference to `PL_body_roots'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_newSV_type':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x6770): undefined reference to `PL_sv_root'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x6774): undefined reference to `PL_sv_count'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x6780): undefined reference to `PL_stashcache'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_SvTRUE_common':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x6ac4): undefined reference to `PL_sv_immortals'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `Perl_sv_setpv_freshbuf':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x74ac): undefined reference to `PL_tainted'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x74b0): undefined reference to `PL_tainting'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `XS_DynaLoader_dl_load_file':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7874): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7878): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `XS_DynaLoader_dl_unload_file':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7ae4): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7ae8): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7af0): undefined reference to `PL_op'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7af4): undefined reference to `PL_curpad'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7afc): undefined reference to `PL_tainted'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `XS_DynaLoader_dl_find_symbol':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7d38): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7d3c): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `XS_DynaLoader_dl_undef_symbols':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7e1c): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x7e20): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `XS_DynaLoader_dl_install_xsub':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x804c): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x8050): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `XS_DynaLoader_dl_error':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x8178): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x817c): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
libperl.a(DynaLoader.o): In function `boot_DynaLoader':
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x82d4): undefined reference to `PL_stack_base'
DynaLoader.c:(.text+0x82d8): undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [perl] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I found that this variables defined in intrpvar.h, but no idea why them missed in objects.

I found that this variables defined in intrpvar.h, but no idea why them missed in objects. I think the MULTIPLICITY define means some, i try to add #include "embedvar.h" to the end of intpvar.h and configure with ant without -Dusemultiplicity, but no luck. I expect to solve this problem with patch some makefiles or sources.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57316710/2173773

Comment: Re "*i try to add #include "embedvar.h" to the end of intpvar.h*", This is a (dynamic?) linking issue, not a compiling issue. I don't know the first thing about cross-compiling, though, so I have no idea what the solution might be.

Comment: Ok, i see. So anyone please tell me what #define definitions should be for unexpected symbols being defined? Why that symbols can de undefined on -Dusethreads or -Duseithreads?